# Use switch statement inside foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in this scenario I'm dealing with two gridviews (gvSnacks and gvSnackCart). gvSnacks contains a fixed list of items with a template button column to "add" the item to gvSnackCart.

The foreach comes into play because I want to make sure that the item hasn't already been placed in the cart. If the user selects an item twice, I want to execute a sql command and make the gvSnackCart quantity of that item go up by 1 (instead of generating a new record).

If the record isn't in the gvSnackCart, the foreach should loop all the way to its default and insert it.

Here's the sql command to insert

```
string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO ShoppingCart…
    ([shopperID], [itemName], [itemType], [quantityOrdered], [unitPrice])…
    VALUES (@shopperID, @itemName, @itemType, @quantityOrdered, @unitPrice)";

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@shopperID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCurrentUser.Text;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = snackDescription;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemType", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "snack";
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@quantityOrdered", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@unitPrice", System.Data.SqlDbType.Money).Value = snackPrice;`

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, myConnection);`
```

Now I get the selected item's name from gvSnacks, and compare with each one present inside gvSnackCart

```
// Retrieve item's name
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

GridViewRow row = gvSnacks.Rows[index];

string snackDescription = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();

// Checks for duplicate snack listing
int duplicate = 0;

foreach (GridViewRow gvRowSnack in gvSnackCart.Rows)
{
    if (gvRowSnack.Cells[1].Text.ToString() == snackDescription)
    {
        duplicate = 1;
    }

    switch (duplicate)
    {
        case 0:
            break;

        case 1:

           //This is the case where it's a duplicate
           //and will be a command to update the record                       
            break;

        default:
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "There was an error while adding the records" + "<br />" + ex.Message;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The gvSnackCart is databound and should update with a new item, unless its a duplicate where it'd do an update. For some reason however it is not functioning. I am not getting an error at runtime. I have tested a read/write with a label so I know I'm retrieving the item name from gvSnacks. I'm also checking the database table and it's not showing any records being added. What seems wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a value of 0,1,or null returned out of a foreach that could then be used in a switch?

Comment: The `duplicate` variable is set in two places: set to 0 when you declare it and to 1 if the snack is a duplicate. So your `switch` statement will only ever hit case 0 or case 1. The default case is essentially "unreachable code" and will never execute.

Answer (score 2):

You can spare yourself a lot of hassle by using LINQ:

```
foreach (var snacks in gvSnackCart.Rows.GroupBy(snack => snack.Cells[1].Text.ToString()))
{
    var p = myCommand.Parameters;
    // I'm largely guessing at these, but hopefully you get the idea.
    p.Add("@shopperID"      , SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCurrentUser.Text;
    p.Add("@itemName"       , SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = snacks.Key;
    p.Add("@itemType"       , SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = /* ??? */;
    p.Add("@quantityOrdered", SqlDbType.Int     ).Value = snacks.Count();
    p.Add("@unitPrice"      , SqlDbType.Money   ).Value = snacks.Sum(r => r.SnackPrice);
    …
}
```